# Math literature for teaching kids

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation

If you were going to teach you kids programming and asked me what book to use as a guide, I would recommend you either [Java programming for kids](http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/java4kids.htm) or [Python for kids](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593274078.do). But what if I want to teach kids math including derivatives, integrals, differential equations, set theory, etc? What book can provide me with a road map I can use (assuming kids are smart enough to learn what I give them)?

Answer (score 3):

There are outlines by Schaum's that have all of those subjects. The outlines are very intuitive and there are problems with given solutions for learning. There are also books called Demystified that offer these subjects with the same format. These books also cover basic algebra, geometry up to topics that include calculus, linear algebra, complex analysis etc.

Comment: I love Schaum's books. They're the best :)